# How should I do to install all dependencies pypi?

Tags: python, setuptools, pypi

I wrote a package available in pypi, python repository and it depends of other packages as I show with the following code of `setup.py` file.

```
try:
    from setuptools import setup
except ImportError:
    from distutils.core import setup

setup(
    name='aTXT',
    packages=['aTXT'],
    # package_data={ '':['*.py'],
    #     'bin': ['bin/*'], 'docx': ['docx/*'], 'pdfminer': ['pdfminer']},
    version=VERSION,
    include_package_data=True,
    # arbitrary keywords
    install_requires=[
            'lxml>=3.2.3',
            'docx>=0.2.0',
            'pdfminer',
            'docopt>=0.6.2',
            'PySide',
            'kitchen>=1.1.1',
            'scandir>=0.8'
    ],
    requires=['docopt', 'scandir', 'lxml', 'PySide', 'kitchen'],
)
```

When I'd tried to install from pip with:

```
pip install aTXT
```

If some of the requirements package are not installed, it raise a Import Error. 
But, why not pip try to install all dependencies?

The following is an example if I don't have `lxml` package installed.

```
ImportError: No module named lxml
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
```

Comment: `dependency_links` ?

Comment: You pointed another way, but I found the cause. The code above works after I run a clean setup inside a virtualenv, I guess that before that, the errors was caused by environments paths.